# w showing wrong number of users logged in

Tags: ssh, users

Can anyone explain me why `w` shows me a wrong number of users currently logged in?

```
root@host ~
# w
 20:14:54 up 17:13,  3 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
root     pts/0    xx.xx.42.51    19:29    0.00s  0.50s  0.00s w
flint    pts/2    xx.xx.42.51    19:53    3:32   0.43s  0.00s tmux a

root@host ~
# who
root     pts/0        Aug 14 19:29 (xx.xx.42.51)
flint    pts/2        Aug 14 19:53 (xx.xx.42.51)

root@host ~
# users
flint root
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/var/run/utmp` can sometimes get corrupt and incorrectly report the number of users that are logged.

If you do a `sudo tee /var/run/utmp < /dev/null` it will get reset. It is not needed to be single-user but it is advisable: logged in users might see some weird results when they try to view users until they log out.

Sources [linuxquestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/w-shows-2-users-when-theres-only-1-a-833203/) and [Redhat mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/redhat-list@redhat.com/msg02706.html).

Comment: Use `last` to get an idea where it went wrong. Example line: `ubuntu   pts/21       :0               Sat Aug  6 23:12    gone - no logout`

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks a lot! Resetting the file fixed the problem :)

Comment: @Lekensteyn You're right. I saw few lines that say 'crashed' etc.

Comment: After reset it shows zero, even I have an active session